# How can i set default answer in Q&A Azure bot

Tags: azure, bots, azure-qna-maker

I want change Default Answer in Q&A Maker Azure Framework Bot, but I cant find field that respond this value. I'm reading documentation (but it looks like it uses an older interface), and I'm trying to find this field but with result.

Here's my current configuration screen:

[image: azure configuration screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're referring to these docs: [QnaMaker - Change Default Answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/change-default-answer)

They're a little confusing, but they key part is:

> You can override this default response **in the bot or application code**
>   calling the endpoint.

Where the docs have this image:

[image: App Service > Configuration > DefaultAnswer]

What they actually mean is that in the QnAMaker Test Console, you can edit the default answer from your Application Settings. Be sure to Save, Train, and Publish your app or the setting may not show.

There's also kind of a way that you can use this setting for your default answer in a bot:

In Node/JS, your bot will not receive that `DefaultAnswer` at all. It receives nothing if there isn't a match, so you have to hard code it with something like:

```js
const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);

// If an answer was received from QnA Maker, send the answer back to the user.
if (qnaResults[0]) {
    await context.sendActivity(qnaResults[0].answer);

// If no answers were returned from QnA Maker, show this reply.
// Note: .getAnswers() does NOT return the default answer from the App Service's Application Settings
} else {
    const defaultAnswer = 'No QnA Maker answers were found. This example uses a QnA Maker Knowledge Base that focuses on smart light bulbs. To see QnA Maker in action, ask the bot questions like "Why won\'t it turn on?" or "I need help."'
    await context.sendActivity(defaultAnswer);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by QnAMaker Test Console, but changing the setting per the picture doesn't seem to do anything. Do you mean I need to save there in the Azure blade, then go back to qna maker and train and publish?

Answer (score 1):

When creating an Azure Web Bot, one of the default Web Chat clients is a fork of microsoft's [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) project, specifically [49 - QnAMaker All Features](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/gary/4.8-dotnet-templates/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features)

The source code for `Dialog/QnAMakerBaseDialog.cs` defines the constant [`DefaultNoAnswer`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/gary/4.8-dotnet-templates/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features/Dialog/QnAMakerBaseDialog.cs#L23):

```cs
public const string DefaultNoAnswer = "No QnAMaker answers found.";
```

And then uses that value when returning a response from [`GetQnAResponseOptionsAsync`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/gary/4.8-dotnet-templates/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features/Dialog/QnAMakerBaseDialog.cs#L57-L73):

```cs
protected async override Task<QnADialogResponseOptions> GetQnAResponseOptionsAsync(DialogContext dc)
{
    var noAnswer = (Activity)Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
    noAnswer.Text = DefaultNoAnswer; // <- used right here

    var cardNoMatchResponse = (Activity)MessageFactory.Text(DefaultCardNoMatchResponse);


    var responseOptions = new QnADialogResponseOptions
    {
        ActiveLearningCardTitle = DefaultCardTitle,
        CardNoMatchText = DefaultCardNoMatchText,
        NoAnswer = noAnswer,
        CardNoMatchResponse = cardNoMatchResponse,
    };

    return responseOptions;
}
```

This particular sample repo doesn't appear to leverage the `DefaultAnswer` configuration key anywhere.

You can opt to include it when available by updating the `noAnswer.Text` like this:

```
- noAnswer.Text = DefaultNoAnswer;
+ noAnswer.Text = this._configuration["DefaultAnswer"] ?? DefaultNoAnswer;
```

You'll also have to pass in the configuration object through the dependency management system. See [this commit](https://github.com/VermontDepartmentOfHealth/covid-bot/commit/b81fd55acc927bc2aca0d15f96ece4812bd4cd17) for a full example.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line in qamakerBaseDialog.js as below

var noAnswer = ActivityFactory.DefaultNoAnswer;

Remove ActivityFactory. and rebuild the code.

```js
constructor(knowledgebaseId, authkey, host) {
        //ActivityFactory.
        var noAnswer = DefaultNoAnswer;
        var filters = [];
        super(knowledgebaseId, authkey, host, noAnswer, DefaultThreshold, DefaultCardTitle, DefaultCardNoMatchText,
            DefaultTopN, ActivityFactory.cardNoMatchResponse, filters, QNAMAKER_BASE_DIALOG);
        this.id = QNAMAKER_BASE_DIALOG;
    }
```